# I'm trying to read a list from an Rest API

Tags: c#, .net, json, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to read a list from a rest API i Created in .net

Here is the class

```
public class Cliente
    {
        public string Cliente1 { get; set; }
        [PrimaryKey]
        public string Correo { get; set; }
        public string Telefono { get; set; }
        public string Calle { get; set; }
        public string Hab { get; set; }
        public string Ciudad { get; set; }
        public string Estado { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Zip { get; set; }
        public int Row { get; set; }
        public string Celular { get; set; }
        public string ID { get; set; }
    }
```

here is the call

```
public Cliente getCliente()
        {
            try
            {
                Cliente cliente;
                var URLWebAPI = "https://www.caja.somee.com/api/Clientes";
                using (var Client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
                {
                    var JSON = Client.GetStringAsync(URLWebAPI);
                    cliente = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Cliente>(JSON.Result);
                }

                return cliente;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

here is the method

```
Repositorio repo = new Repositorio();
            Cliente listacliente = repo.getCliente();
            ListaClientes.ItemsSource = listacliente.Cliente1;
```

here is the xaml view

```
<ListView x:Name="ListaClientes" BackgroundColor="White" VerticalOptions="Fill" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" SeparatorColor="LightGray">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Cliente1}"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"   TextColor="DarkRed"  />

                                    </Grid>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

and this is the error

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'AppCaja.Cliente' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '', line 1, position 1.'

i really need your help, i woul like to make it works

Comment: You should post the JSON you are trying to deserialize.  My guess is it is an array of items (the JSON starts and ends with `[` and `]`)  but you are trying to deserialize to a single item.  You should be able to fix by deserializing into a `List<Cliente>` instead of a `Cliente`.

Comment: It seems like the issue is that you are trying to deserialize the JSON response into a single Cliente object rather than into a list of Cliente. It might be helpful to inspect the JSON string in the debugger to see what the response looks like and figure out how to adapt the deserialization to match.

Answer (score 1):

1. The API is returning XML, you need to update this.
2. You need configure your client to read Json.

>

```
using (var Client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
{
 //This line
 Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 
 MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));    

 var JSON = Client.GetStringAsync(URLWebAPI);
 cliente = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Cliente>(JSON.Result);
}
```

Comment: Let me know if it helps you.